# SQL - Counting Users That Have Multiple Inputs In Another Column

Tags: sql, count, aggregate-functions, having-clause

This should be easy, I'm just stuck.

I want to count the amount of users that have multiple accounts.

Example:

```
account | user
1         1
2         1
3         1
4         2
5         2
6         3
7         4
8         5
9         6
10        6
```

This would result in 3 users that have multiple accounts associated with their user id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `group by` and `having`. If you want the list of users that have more than one account, then:

```
select user
from mytable
group by user
having count(*) > 1
```

This assumes no duplicates `(user, account)`. Else, you need to change the `having` clause to:

```
having count(distinct account) > 1
```

Or:

```
having min(account) <> max(account)
```

Now, if you want the count of such users, just add another level of aggregation:

```
select count(*) cnt
from (
    select user
    from mytable
    group by user
    having count(*) > 1
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count(distinct)` with filtering:

```
select count(distinct user)
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.user = t.user and t2.account <> t.account
             );
```